# HTML5 drag and drop to rearrange widgets in a grid?

Tags: javascript, html, drag

I have a dashboard made up of an imaginary grid of widgets, the grid has 2 rows and each row has 3 slots. I want a user to be able to drag a piece of content to a different slot whereupon it displaces the content already in the slot (pushing it over to the right, potentially off the grid). I'm using this code to handle the drag and drop. How can I detect collisions and displace the widget in the slot being targeted?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function allowDrop(ev)
{
ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev)
{
ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev)
{
ev.preventDefault();
var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
</script>
```

Each gridslot is something like this:

```
<div id="gridslot" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"/>
<div id="widget" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"/>Some Content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pseudo code

```
function setContent(targetCell, content) {
    if (targetCell is off the grid)
        return;

    if (targetCell.content is not empty) {
        // we need to shift the targets content to the right
        setContent(targetCell.nextCellToTheRight, targetcell.content);
    }

    targetCell.content = content;
}
```

Notice that it recursively shifts things to the right to make room, potentially moving the entire row if necessary.

Comment: Thanks. Hoping for more responses/more specifics. If only I could use pseudocode.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but I would have a look at this jquery plugin: [Html5 Sortable](http://farhadi.ir/projects/html5sortable/)